# Why Navigation.goBack() not working properly?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I am using following way to create navigation system

StackNavigator -> DrawerNavigator -> (Screen A, Screen B, Screen C)

Screen A is initial Route

Screen A to Screen B Using

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen B")  //Working Fine
```

Screen B to Screen C Using

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen C")  //Working Fine
```

In Screen C

```
this.props.navigation.goBack() //Not Working
```

But

```
this.props.navigation.goBack(null) //It's going to Screen A instead of Screen B
```

What's wrong here.

Please help me Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you didn't show the navigation structure of the drawer, I don't know how the 3 screens are put inside of it. I'm assuming they are 3 different drawerScreens

This happens because you are using a DrawerNavigation, that doesn't create a history of screens when you navigate around it.

To solve this you have to change the navigation structure to something like:

```
DrawerNavigation => StackNavigator => Screen A, B, C
```

Comment: Then how to set drawerLockMode: "locked-closed" if i put screens inside StackNavigator?

Comment: It took me a whole week to find the problem, thank you so much man. <3

Answer (score 3):

You can specify backBehavior="history" inside Drawer.Navigator and it shouldn't move you to the initial root on goBack anymore :)

**Example:**

```
 <Drawer.Navigator
      backBehavior="history"
    >
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As the answer above is, the drawer navigators are not in the stack, so you can't tell the path of your journey.

the `key` property for `goBack()` is a dynamically created string, created by `react-navigation` whenever navigate to a new route.

These stack keys are stored in `this.props.navigation.state`

> NOTE: Use `.goBack(null)` if your goal is to return to any place
>   without specifying a closing target.

Like this example, you can add to the stack.

**Example**

```js
const Drawers = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    A: {
      screen: HomeScreen
    },
   ...
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "A"
  }
);

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Drawers: {
      screen: Drawers
    },
    otherStack: {
      screen: otherStack
    },
    ....
```